# How to find the irreducible constituents of a Brauer character with MAGMA?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, magma-cas

I'd like to ask the following MAGMA-question:

How to find the irreducible constituents of a Brauer character with MAGMA?

Let $G$ be a finite group. Moreover, let $k$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$, such that $p$ divides $|G|$. Furthermore suppose that $k$ is a splitting field for $G$.

Let $M$ be a $kG$-module with Brauer character $\phi$.

> How can I find the multiplicities of the elements of IBr in $\phi$ with MAGMA?

Example ( This $k$ should be a splitting field for $G$ in char. 3.):

```
G:=Sym(6);
K:=GF(81);
PIMs:=ProjectiveIndecomposableModules(G,K);
sim:=IrreducibleModules(G,K);
IBr:=[BrauerCharacter(j) : j in sim];
proj3:=PIMs[3];
brchar:=BrauerCharacter(proj3);

Decomposition(IBr,brchar);
```

yielded

```
[
0,
0,
9/8,
0,
0,
0,
0
]
( 63/2, -15/4, 15/4, 0, 0, 0, 1/4, 0, 17/8, 0, 0 )
```

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find my mistake.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: It would be simpler in this example to find the constituents of $\mathtt{proj3}$ directly using $\mathtt{ConstituentsWithMultiplicities}$.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @YCor You could this calculation on the Magma calculator, which is freely available online (I just did, although I have extreme difficulty spelling constitutents) .